# Are there any problem if I use .NET Core as a Backend replacing the Nextjs Api Routes?

Tags: .net-core, next.js

I'm developing an E-Commerce Website with NextJs, I know I can build a full application with NextJS Front-End and Back-End so the question is are there any troubles like with SEO or something related about that if I replace NextJS API routes and choose .NET Core.

I'm more familiar with .NET Core as a backend than Nextjs Api Routes.

Comment: No there isn't any issue though you may need to set origin headers in backend to allow requests from your frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next.js doesn't care where data come from and it does not affect SEO. But you should know how to setup.NET to response to the request which come from Next.js application.